# Running flutter on a real iOS device Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project

Tags: xcode, flutter, provisioning-profile, code-signing-certificate, flutter-ios

I've been facing this problem when i try to run my flutter app on a physical ios device and tried everything I could find but nothing works.

```
Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
Uncategorized (Xcode): Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code

Error (Xcode): Framework not found Flutter


Error launching application on iPhone.
```

and before the error occurs when the run starts it shows me this message:
`Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: xxxxxxJTM` and the key **xxxxxxxJTM** is not my key because when i look in  xcode runner sign in and capabilities my team key looks like: **xxxxxxx733** and i'm using vscode by the way.

I tried:

- pod repo update
- pod setup
- flutter clean
- pub cache clean
- pub cache repair
- pod deintegrate
- flutter build --ios
  i also went to keychain on my mac and deleted all the certificates and dev team accounts
  same thing on xcode

Comment: Did you try to run it using Xcode? What was the result?

Comment: @AhmetKAYGISIZ i did try building it on xcode and it shows me an error that repeats with multiple packages and it says: Flutter framework not found

Comment: You opened "Runner.xcworkspace" in "/ios" folder, right? Did you run "pod install" too?

Comment: @AhmetKAYGISIZ yes, even when i tried to run a whole new fresh project it would not work, I updated my osx and flutter to the latest version after changing the team on xcode: com.xxxx.myapp to com.myname.myapp it magically worked